# TV movie about a family on a spaceship to Andromeda who go through a black hole

Tags: story-identification, space

I remember a TV movie I saw after school in the 70's.

It was about a family going on a space ship to the Andromeda galaxy (no I am not talking about Lost In Space).

They have some crisis and end up going through a black hole presenting the opportunity for future shows which as far as I know never happened.

I believe their space ship was shaped similar to the body of a 727 airliner without the wings.

I have never seen this movie again although for the 70's it was pretty good.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_Star_Voyager possibly?

Comment: Or possibly - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_After_Tomorrow_%28TV_special%29 Aired as a NBC Special Treat episode in 1975.

Comment: I'm with JohnP on this one. I think he nailed it with the Day after Tomorrow. JohnP you ought to put it as the answer.

Comment: Gawd I remember loving Earth Star Voyager... especially as it ended with them fighting a giant transformer (least that's the way I remember it).

Answer (score 6):

This does totally sound like the 1975/1976 TV film *The Day After Tomorrow*. Quoting from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_After_Tomorrow_%28TV_special%29)'s plot summary:

> In the future, the survival of human civilisation is increasingly threatened by rising pollution, environmental damage and the depletion of the Earth's natural resources. The narrator (Ed Bishop) introduces Space Station Delta and the "lightship" Altares – the latter of which is the first Earth spacecraft to "harness the limitless power of the photon", allowing it to travel at the speed of light. Altares is due to leave Delta on a mission beyond the Solar System to seek out Earth-like planets for possible colonisation.
>
> [image]
>
> However, disaster strikes when Altares is caught in the gravity of a black hole that has formed from a collapsed star. The photon drive is unable to provide the faster-than-light speeds necessary to break free; nevertheless, Anna urges the crew not to give up hope, for she suspects that the object may be a gateway to another universe. Her theory is proven correct when, sustaining the various space-time distortions at the event horizon, Altares safely emerges from the black hole – intact, albeit with no way of returning to Earth. As the vessel and its intrepid crew approach a planet, the narrator concludes, "One thing is sure – this is not the final word. Not the end, but the beginning. A new universe, a new hope? Only time will tell."

I remember when they exited the black hole, the stars were very large and bright crosses, right?

Comment: This is just stating agreement with information already posted (in [this comment](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/75636/#comment157163_75636)) and then asking a question about it.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! Please expand on this in order to make it a good answer (i.e. what details in the question match The Day After Tomorrow?). As is, this would be better as a comment. Please take a look at the [help] to learn how this site works.

Comment: I've edited your answer to include a summary of the parts of this film that seem to match the OP's question. Please bear this in mind when answering future story-ID questions: saying "the answer is *this* film, because it matches the question in *these* ways" is much better than just saying "the answer is *this* film".